# SELECT через VBA модуль

Tags: sql, access, vba, office

Допустим, перед выполнением запроса требуется немного разжевать данные(Создать временные таблицы с расчетами т п), что бы потом заджонить на них какую-то таблицу.
Можно ли это как-нибудь сделать через модуль? Т.е я врубаю макрос, он создает мне нужные таблицы, а потом в конце выполняется запрос на Select и открывается окно с выборкой?

Да, можно обойтись без темповых таблиц, использую , допустим подзапросы, но может пострадать производительность. 
Да, можно выполнить подготовительные запросы руками, но если их штук 5, то это неудобно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете создать запросы на создание таблиц на основе выборки. Access в этом случае генерирует запрос типа `select [field1] from [table1] into [temptable]`.
Можно в коде через RunSQL просто выполнять такие sql-запросы.
А потом загоняете все в макрос/VBA-код и выполняете в нужном порядке.